# how to resolve runtime error in asp.net while hosting website

Tags: asp.net, web.config-transform

i done my work on local. All pages of aspx is working properly but when i upload my website to remote server. i face this error ....

> Runtime Error
>   Description: Failure of an application on the server. For security reasons, the current custom settings to prevent application failures remotely view more details about the error encountered. These details can be displayed in the browser but run locally on the server.
>
> Details: To enable the display of the details of this specific error message on the remote server, create a tag  in a configuration file "web.config" in the root directory of the current web. The "mode" attribute of the tag  must be set to "Off".

```
<! - Web.Config Configuration File -> 
<configuration> 
    <system.web> 
        <customErrors mode="Off"/> 
    </ system.web> 
</ configuration>
```

> Note: You can customize the error page by modifying the current attribute "defaultRedirect"  application configuration tag to point to the URL of a custom error page.

Please tell me how can i remove this error and see my asp pages on internet browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting some error that is not shown to you. You have to turn  the [customErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mode to `off` or set `RemoteOnly` to see the error, you might be getting `exception` while accessing database. Once you know the error you can fix that error and set the mode to `On` again in customErrors tag in **web.config**.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="url" mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```